# Does a spherical potential mean spherical mass distribution?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, potential, planets, multipole-expansion

I came across this question is Binney & Tremaine's galactic dynamics. I'm pretty sure that the answer is no, but struggling to come up with an example.[image]

Comment: The key here is "non-zero multipole moments"

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633).

Comment: If there was a departure from sphericity you would encounter non-zero multipole moments. For example a mass quadrupole.